# how to make a simple multithreading?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

Okay, now I was making a mobile application like restaurant finder, I want to show a photo of the restaurant

the example : `restaurant x <image x>`

It's a code:

```
if (ImageToDisplay != nil)
{
   NSData * imageData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: ImageToDisplay.URL]]autorelease];
   ImageForRestaurant.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

The problem is this process of downloading pictures may take too long. So I want the process to be run on a different thread.

That way the code after that can run without having to wait this one to finish.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (ImageToDisplay != nil) {
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImage:) object:ImageToDisplay];
}

- (void)loadImage:(ImageToDisplay *)image { //Background method
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSData * imageData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: ImageToDisplay.URL]]autorelease];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageForRestaurant:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)setImageForRestaurant:(NSData *)imageData { //Change UI in main thread
    ImageForRestaurant.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

I've just included basics in multi-threading; I guess it will serve your purpose

Comment: what's the auto release in loadImage for?

Comment: There is no class called ImageToDisplay

Comment: why this code : [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImage:) loadImage:ImageToDisplay]; doen't work. I add import NSTread at header but it said the header not found. can u give me a framework of NSTread? is it need NSTread.h?

Comment: @Jim Thio, sorry there was an edit in the 'performSelectorInBackground', please try it. Also you need not to import any classes for multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ASIHTTPRequest library. See *'Creating an asynchronous request'* on this page: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Also the new library [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking) looks promising. As they say:

> If you're tired of massive libraries that try to do too much, if you've taken it upon yourself to roll your own hacky solution, if you want a library that actually makes iOS networking code kinda fun, try out AFNetworking.

Comment: @Armen [re: edit] I feel the URL is more descriptive than "this page". It is semantically correct and informative.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

`- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg`

I think it's the easiest way.